# Verilog-Got Error for Force description when [] is included in target instance

Tags: verilog

I got a problem when I run the simulation with the below statement,

```
force top.AA_B[100].i0.QB[1] = 1'b0
```

VCS simulator report below Error:

> Invalid index in cross-module reference due to index is out of bound.

How can I run the simulation with above force statement?

Answer (score 0):

Bit or part select of nets or vectors can not be forced.
Thus for a vector it is all or nothing.

Comment: That is not true; I do it all the time.  We need a [mcve] for this Question.

Comment: My simulators do NOT allow this. I tried to find the relevant section the best I could find was: System Verilog standard section 5.6 Nets, regs, and logic: *A single force or release statement shall not be
applied to a whole or part of a variable that is being assigned by a mixture of continuous and procedural
assignmen*